# angular 2 es5 component route

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to implement Angular 2 routing using ES5.

Following is appComponent

```
(function(app) {
  app.AppComponent =function() {};
  app.AppComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
      selector: 'my-app'
    }).
    View({
        templateUrl: 'app.html',
        directives: [ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {
          this.name = "pankaj Badukale";
      }
    });

    **ng.router.RouteConfig([
        {
            path: "login",
            component: app.LoginComponent,
            as: "login"
        }
    ]);**

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

app.html

```
<h1>
    {{name}}  
    <a [routerLink]="['/login']">Home</a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</h1>
```

I want to know how we can config routing on component.

I have searched lot but people just defined up to view, component, class.

Do anyone have idea?

Comment: please have a look at this solution. It could help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34604160/angular-2-routing-in-es5

Comment: Sorry but with Beta.0 of angular 2 syntax has changed, means some advance syntax came. So I am expecting answer with respect to it. Currently looking in lib for it................

Answer (score 1):

Component and RouteConfig both are decorators, you can write decorators in angular 2(beta) like

```
app.AppComponent = ng.core.Component(...)(app.AppComponent);
app.AppComponent = ng.router.RouteConfig(...)(app.AppComponent);
```

here is your working copy...

```
(function(app) {
  app.AppComponent =function() {};
  app.AppComponent = ng.core
    .Component({
      selector: 'my-app'
    }).
    View({
        templateUrl: 'app.html',
        directives: [ng.router.ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
    })
    .Class({
      constructor: function() {
          this.name = "pankaj Badukale";
      }
    });

    app.AppComponent = ng.router.RouteConfig([
        {
            path: "login",
            component: app.LoginComponent,
            as: "login"
        }
    ])(app.AppComponent);

})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```